# (Revisted) Surjectivity: Examples for Compositions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, function-and-relation-composition

I'm asked to give an example where $f$ is surjective, but $g\circ f$ is not. I suspect that $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ will do the trick, namely for $f,g : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, right?

---

Well, what about where $g$ is surjective...

Comment: Since $\not\exists x\in X : (g\circ f) (x)=z$, where $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Z$.

Comment: $g$ must be defined on the entire range of $f$. But as stated, you could simply use $g \equiv \operatorname{const}$, I suspect there are more constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\operatorname{f}$ is surjective, the surjectivity of $\operatorname{g} \circ \operatorname{f}$ depends on $\operatorname{g}$ alone. In fact the image of $\operatorname{g} \circ \operatorname{f}$ is just the image of $\operatorname{g}$. You can choose any non-surjective function $\operatorname{g}$ and $\operatorname{g}\circ \operatorname{f}$ will fail to be surjective.

Your example $\operatorname{g}(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ works fine since $\operatorname{g}$ misses $0$, i.e. there is no $x$ for which $\frac{1}{x}=0$. Other simple examples include $\operatorname{g}(x) = x^2$, $\operatorname{g}(x) = \operatorname{e}^x$ or even the constant function $\operatorname{g}(x) = 0$.

Comment: @Trancot You're very welcome. I'm glad that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably the simplest example (as mentioned in the comments) is to take any surjective $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and let $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be constant.